# How to pass variables to Javascript in cakephp using window.app

Tags: javascript, variables, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In my cakephp2 app I'm trying to pass a variable from my layout to Javascript.

I'm using the following code:

```
$test = array('a'=>'test');
$this->Js->set('data', json_encode($test));
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

Which results in the following HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {window.app = {"data":"{\"a\":\"test\"}"};});
//]]>
</script>
```

However when I try to reach window.app in my chrome console, I get the error "window.app is undefined".

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript variable was set on document ready which you can't access globally so set `onDomReady` to false to access globally.

```
    $test = array('a'=>'test');
    $this->Js->set('data', json_encode($test));
    echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('onDomReady' => false));
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately that gives the same result "window.app is undefined".

Comment: But shouldn't I be able to see window.app in my chrome/firebug console? Because there it can't be reached.

Comment: My bad, it works perfectly now. array('onDomReady' => false) did the trick. Thanks!